# Jbutton over Jbutton background image?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, sprite

Lets say I created a 2d tile map with jbuttons and then created units on top of the map is there a way to show the background of the map when the unit(also a jbutton) is on top of the tile, because how it is now is the background of the unit is just colored red, so is it possible to do this with jbuttons over jbuttons?

Comment: What if you make the Topmost JButton `Translucent` will that do, for your case ?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, use the opaque property

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452753/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-jbutton-on-top-of-a-jbutton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible, yes, advisable, ah, probably not.

I believe you're going to need to change the layout of the title button to something you can control (this is going to depend upon your visual requirements).

I, personally, would probably go for a panel with a label inside it, using mouse listeners to monitor for mouse actions & probably input/action maps for keyboard interaction.

Jbuttons are just jcomponent, so they get all the functionality that jcomponents have

Comment: Yea I know but my other team mates used jbuttons over jbuttons and I wanted to see if there was a easy way to do it similar to jpanels

Comment: Look, it's fine. A jbuttin is just a jcomponent, this means you add other components to it and adjust the layout to suit your needs

Answer (score 3):

If the Topmost JButton being `Translucent` can solve your purpose, here is one example code, how you can do that. Simply change the `AlphaComposite` values i.e. `0.7f`, used in my case, to whatever deemed fit for your instance of the code :

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TransparentButton
{       
    private CustomButton button;
    private ImageIcon backgroundImage;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Transparent Button");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        try
        {
            backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(
                    new URL("http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/" + 
                            "gaganisonline/images/404error.jpg"));
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        JButton baseButton = new JButton(backgroundImage);
        baseButton.setOpaque(true);
        baseButton.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

        button = new CustomButton("Transparent Button");
        baseButton.add(button);

        contentPane.add(baseButton);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new TransparentButton().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomButton extends JButton
{
    private BufferedImage buttonImage = null;

    public CustomButton(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if (buttonImage == null ||
                buttonImage.getWidth() != getWidth() ||
                    buttonImage.getHeight() != getHeight())
        {
            buttonImage = (BufferedImage) createImage(
                                getWidth(), getHeight());                               
        }   

        Graphics gButton = buttonImage.getGraphics();
        gButton.setClip(g.getClip());
        super.paint(gButton);
        /*
         * Make the graphics object sent to 
         * this paint() method translucent.
         */     
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AlphaComposite newComposite = 
            AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.7f);
        g2.setComposite(newComposite);      
        /*
         * Copy the JButton's image to the destination
         * graphics, translucently.      
         */         
        g2.drawImage(buttonImage, 0, 0, null);          
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the same :

[image: TRANSPARENT BUTTON]

Comment: not quite what I'm looking for, its more like a unit over the a background and the unit's image where it is empty the background is shown, so basically like a overlay image on top of another image, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Seems like for the scenario you want, `JButton` is really not the right choice, as described by @MadProgrammer , I guess that answer goes miles :-)

Comment: @GagandeepBali Great eg +1

Comment: @joeyrohan : Thankyou and KEEP SMILING :-)